# SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException when authorizing from Xamarin.ios using MSAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a .NET Core Web Application and Web Api that I am calling from an IOS app (using Xamarin.ios). The web application is hosted in IIS on a private server.  I am using MSAL single tenant to authenticate. That part seems to be working fine, as I can log in and get an access token.

The browser works fine, I can navigate to the WebApi no problem. However, when I try to make an http request to my Api, I get a 401 in my app. Here's the call:

```
string accessToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AccessToken");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
//_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/{uriSuffix}");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string reply = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return reply;
```

Debugging the server, I'm getting:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: 'IDX10511: Signature validation failed.
```

In the PII of the exception, it has my email, name, etc, leading me to believe that it successfully got my info from the token.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your Web API use Microsoft.Identity.Web ? See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis
The Web API that are created with ASP.NET core templates / file new project use the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint, whereas MSAL uses the v2.0 endpoint.

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur I figured out what my issue was. I'll add an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue (or at least got it working). It had to do with the Audience. What is the Audience, you say? I couldn't tell you. But mine wasn't working because it's SINGLE-TENANT. Most tutorials I read used multi-tentant, which is handled differently.

Here's the change:

```
  private IPublicClientApplication _pca;
        readonly string[] Scopes = 
        {
            "<tenant_id>/<api_permission>"
        };

        public AuthenticationHelper()
        {
            _pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(<tenant_id>)
                .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
                .WithRedirectUri("msauth.<bundle_id>://auth")
                .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<client_id>/v2.0")
                .Build();
        }
```

The important bit is the "Scopes" variable. Note, I prefix the api permission with "tenant_id\", where tenant_id is the guid of my tenant. Once I added that, it worked.